# Range in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have written this code to merge a few lines in each column, from column C to AZ.

For some reason the range does not match the one I was expecting, in this case the code merges the cells C8:C10 then D8:D12, E8:E12, and so on. lines = 2 in this example.

I don't understand why aren't the ranges matching if lines value is not changing inside the for.

Thanks!

```
For columns = 0 To 49


    Range(Range("C8").Offset(0, columns), Range("C8").Offset((lines), columns)).Select
         With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 90
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
        End With

next comlumns
```

Comment: use `Option Explicit` first of all and you'll see a typo which should be a large portion of your problems.

Answer (score 2):

`Columns` is a reserved word. And you said that this code did run?

If I change that to a valid variable then the code runs. The problem is the way you are using Offset

`?[C8].offset(2).address` after the way you merge will give you `$C$12`

Also avoid the use of `.Select` [INTERESTING READ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select) And not to mention fully qualify your objects. For example your range and cell objects are not fully qualified and may give you error.

I think, this is what you are trying to achieve?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim i As Long, rw As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    rw = 2

    With ws
        For i = 3 To 52
            Set rng = .Range(.Cells(8, i), .Cells(8 + rw, i))

             With rng
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 90
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = True
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think the OP's code could have run with the For/Next loop broken (note misspelling on the `Next` part)

Comment: @enderland; Yeah I already noted that when I was testing it. I didn't mention it as I finally changed the damn offending variable :p

Comment: I added the typo in the browser. I forgot to copy this line and manually mistyped it. Weirdly enough (I'm not very familiar with VBA) the word columns as a variable is working fine. I understand though the idea of making a cleanr code and will study Siddaharth solution to learn something. I made it work yesterday but I have much more stuff to add and a cleaner code will definitely help me! Thanks!